# copy csv file from local machine to remtoe server with serial column

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I need to copy the file into a table from local to remote, the problem is the table has a serial id column the not in the file,
when I'm trying to copy the table is missing a column and I'm getting an error because the data types are not matching.
this is the Table:

```
CREATE TABLE simulation_price_list
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    dt date,
    t time without time zone,
    name text,
    price numeric
)
```

this is the code:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    outputquery = "COPY {0} from STDIN WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV;".format('simulation_book_data')
    cur.copy_expert(outputquery, f)
```

I also tried this command:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        cur.copy_from(f, 'simulation_price_list', sep=',', columns=(
        'id', 'dt', 't', 'name', 'price'))
```

this is how a line in the file look like:

```
'2021-09-01','16:19:58.391749','david',41.1900
```

this is the errer:

```
sycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for integer: "'2021-09-01'"
CONTEXT:  COPY simulation_price_list, line 1, column file_line_seq: "'2021-09-01'"
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

`columns=('id', 'dt', 't', 'name', 'price')`

should be:

`columns=('dt', 't', 'name', 'price')`.

The `id` column will automatically be filled by the sequence behind the `serial` 'type'.

`serial` is really a macro that expands to:

`integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')`

See here [Serial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) for more information.